# gtk-error **: gtk_text_btree_previous_line ran out of lines aborting

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

Backstory: I am doing a irc bot with a gui. I have a textbuffer to show chat.(telling the textbuffer thing because I think it might be the problem)

The bot runs ok for a couple of seconds and then gives this error:

```
gtk-error **: gtk_text_btree_previous_line ran out of lines aborting...
```

My code is [here](https://github.com/BlasterJoni/NekoMaid_BOT). The main file is run.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well im fumb I first tested this code:

```
if chatbuffer.get_line_count() > 10:
    chatbuffer.delete(chatbuffer.get_iter_at_line(0), chatbuffer.get_iter_at_line(5))
```

To know if it worked, bu then forgot to change the 10 to 500 on the final code, and it stayed like this:

```
if chatbuffer.get_line_count() > 10:
    chatbuffer.delete(chatbuffer.get_iter_at_line(0), chatbuffer.get_iter_at_line(250))
```

And that was the cause of the error, as soon as changed it to 500 it started working:

```
if chatbuffer.get_line_count() > 500:
    chatbuffer.delete(chatbuffer.get_iter_at_line(0), chatbuffer.get_iter_at_line(250))
```